# Вывести имя и фамилию самых бедных клиентов

Tags: sql, oracle

Нужно вывести имя и фамилию самых бедных клиентов - среди замужних женщин, не проживающих ни в Японии, ни в Бразилии, ни в Италии. Богатство определяется по кредитному лимиту.[image: Диаграмма]

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT (нужные поля)
FROM   (список таблиц через запятую)
WHERE  (список условий соответствия и отбора через AND)
ORDER  BY (кредитный лимит) ASC
FETCH  FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES
```